# Ignore specified column while highlighting

Tags: python, pandas, termcolor

Here is my DataFrame...

```
from termcolor import colored
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [0, 15, 10, 5, 20, 17], 'Col2': [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8], 'Col3': [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],

         'Col4': [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23], 'Col5': [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I'm trying to highlight 3 lagest values in each column with red(1st largest), blue(2nd largest) & magenta(3rd largest) color excluding Col2 & Col4.

I tried as ...

```
columns_to_exclude = ['Col2', 'Col4']

def highlighted(column):

    filtered_df = df.drop(columns=columns_to_exclude)

    values = column.nlargest(3).tolist()

    colors = []

    for x in column:

        if x in values:

            if x == values[0]:

                colors.append(colored(str(x), None, 'on_red'))

            elif x == values[1]:

                colors.append(colored(str(x), None, 'on_blue'))

            elif x == values[2]:

                colors.append(colored(str(x), None, 'on_magenta'))

        else:

            colors.append(colored(str(x), 'white'))

    return colors

for col in df.columns:

    df[col] = highlighted(df[col])

df.columns = [colored(col, None, 'on_black') for col in df.columns]

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

But getting all the 5 columns to be highlighted as par my defined coloured.
Where I'm wrong ????
Is there any more shorter and simpler way too ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the `name` when use `apply`:

```
def hightlight(series, excluded, special_col, special_val):
    # handle special case
    if series.name == special_col:
        special_val = str(special_val)
        return series.astype(str).apply(lambda x: colored(x, None, 'on_yellow') if x == special_val else
                                            colored(x, 'white') )

    # general case
    if series.name in excluded:
        return series.astype(str).apply(lambda x: colored(x, 'white'))
    colors = pd.Series([(None,'on_red'),(None,'on_blue'), (None,'on_magenta')]
                            + [('white',)]*(len(series)-3),
                        index=series.sort_values(ascending=False).index
                    ).reindex(series.index)

    return [colored(str(x), *c) for x,c in zip(series, colors)]

    
print(df.apply(hightlight, excluded=columns_to_exclude, special_col='Col4', special_val=18)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: colored(x, 'white', None))
)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm using pydroid3 mobile app where df.apply does not work. Can you do it like my script using termcolor in few lines plz

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia my bad, I only updated a part of the code. Fixed.

Comment: @Quant Horang plz do something for column alignment.thanks.

Comment: @Quant Horang sir how to drop index column?? I'm trying....print(df.apply(hightlight, excluded=columns_to_exclude)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: colored(x, 'white', None).to_string((index=False))))

Comment: Yes, chain with `.to_string(index=False)` (only one pair of parentheses).

Comment: Sir one last query -- if I want to highlight any certain value in one of excluded colum let's say in "Col4" I want to highlight "18" on_yellow, how to do that in this script plz

Comment: Sir just 2 more lines plz --- in my DataFrame there are +ve & -ve values in some columns. I want to highlight text "Red" for -ve values in all columns whrere present (I have used dummy for my question so no -ve values there.). Thanks

Comment: sir plz solve my last query

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from termcolor import colored

data = {
    "Col1": [0, 15, 10, 5, 20, 17],
    "Col2": [11, 6, 3, 16, 21, 8],
    "Col3": [2, 17, 12, 7, 22, 9],
    "Col4": [3, 8, 13, 18, 3, 23],
    "Col5": [4, 19, 8, 11, 6, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.columns = [colored(str(c), "white", None) for c in df]

for c in df:
    if any(x in c for x in ("Col2", "Col4")):
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: colored(str(x), "white", None))
        continue

    largest = df[c].nlargest(3)
    colormap = dict(zip(map(str, largest), ("on_red", "on_blue", "on_magenta")))
    mask = df[c].isin(largest)

    df[c] = df[c].astype(str)

    df.loc[mask, c] = df.loc[mask, c].apply(
        lambda x: colored(str(x), None, colormap.get(x, "on_black"))
    )
    df.loc[~mask, c] = df.loc[~mask, c].apply(
        lambda x: colored(str(x), None, "on_black")
    )

print(df)
```

Prints (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me wrong in my script plz and what if I want to give any background colour to my headers.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia In `highlighted()` function you create `filtered_df` but don't use it. just put `if column.name in columns_to_exclude: return column` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thanks but now column alignment disturbed.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia You should color the column names as well, eg. put there only white color `df.columns = [colored(str(c), "white", None) for c in df]`

Comment: Still alignment not achieved.

Comment: @BrijeshChaurasia Maybe you have diacritics or special unicode characters in column names? If `print(df)` without any coloring is aligned, it should be aligned if you color every cell/header name too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html)/[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)/[`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) :

```
top3 = {1: "red", 2: "blue", 3: "magenta"}

def fn(ser):
    return (
        ser.rank(ascending=False, method="dense").map(
            lambda x: f"background-color: {top3.get(x)}").fillna("")
    )

s = df.style.apply(fn, subset=df.columns.difference(columns_to_exclude))
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I need to do by termcolor because df.style not working in my pydroid3 mobile app. Can you suggest me some smaller script plz by using termcolor

Comment: plz can you help me with termcolor script. Your script is too short so I will like it.